# Redirecting the output in shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script.

Say in script test.sh below are thw two prcoess i launch through script

1.echo execute Test.sh start

2.java process1 > /dev/null

3.java process2 > /dev/null

4.echo execute Test.sh finish

5.exit

Now if i run test.sh, say process1 is running and process2 will kill the process1 based on certain condition, so when it kills the process 1, it outputs , this output i want to redirect.

Now output is 
execute Test.sh start

test.sh line :2 killed pid java process1 > /dev/null

execute Test.sh finish

I want it to look like below, so how to redirect it.

execute Test.sh start

execute Test.sh finish

I hope i am clear in my question framing now

Comment: Do you mean process1 will restart?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered redirecting error stream

java process1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

java process2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

EDIT:
I think you are asking how to redirect bash shell's output. Use the following:

```
bash > output.txt
java process1 > /dev/null
java process2 > /dev/null
exit
```

EDIT 2:
Seems like there is only one ugly way to do it, which may not satisfy your needs.

```
bash > output.txt
java process1 > output1
java process2 > output2
exit
cat output1
cat output2
rm output1 output2
```

EDIT 3:
It seems there can be another way. Try other shells which may not print out process number when it is killed.

Comment: the echo output has to come, only the killed output should not come, sohow to redirect this?

Comment: It was good answer, but this i cannot use because, the echo messages have to be shown on the shell console then and there only !!